# Pass parameters into ansible include_tasks

Tags: ansible

I wrote tasks that manipulate log files. I need to create a playbook that gets all logs files and
run the tasks over it.

I get all logs files using

```
---
- name: loop task
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
          - name: "find all logs file in {{folder_path}}"
            find:
                    paths: "{{folder_path}}/"
                    file_type: file
                    use_regex: yes
                    patterns: "*.log"
            register: results

          - name: loop over all files
            include_tasks: file_tasks.yml
            vars:
                    logs_path: ["{{results.files.path}}"]
```

log_path is the var name in the file_tasks.yml that make the manipulation.

How can I pass the file_tasks.yml file by file?

Thanks

Comment: `patterns: "*.log"` is a file glob (shell) not a python regex. You should set `use_regex: no` (default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to change loop playbook like:

```
---
- name: loop task
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
          - name: "find all logs file in {{folder_path}}"
            find:
                    paths: "{{folder_path}}/"
                    file_type: file
                    patterns: "*.log"
            register: results

          - name: loop over all files
            include_tasks: file_tasks.yml
            vars:
                    logs_path: "{{item.path}}"
            loop: "{{results.files}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the files

```sh
shell> tree log
log
├── service1.log
├── service2.log
└── service3.log
```

the task

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: log
        file_type: file
        patterns: "*.log"
      register: results
    - debug:
        var: item.path
      loop: "{{ results.files }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item.path: log/service3.log
  item.path: log/service2.log
  item.path: log/service1.log
```

---

If you want to process the iteration in the included file create one. For example put the debug task into the file

```yaml
shell> cat file_tasks.yml 
- debug:
    var: item.path
```

Then the include gives the same results

```yaml
    - include_tasks: file_tasks.yml
      loop: "{{ results.files }}"
```

You can specify the name of the variable for each loop using `loop_var` with [loop_control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var).